# Conjunctions 'like' and 'as' after the verb 'look'

Tags: grammar

Is the use of 'like' correct in this sentence? 
The horse looked like it was running.

Or here should be as (as if).

Comment: Yes, "like" is in competition with "as if/though".  Strictly speaking "as if/though" is preferable, since some people say that "like" is a preposition that requires a noun phrase complement. "Like" is certainly OK in informal style.

Comment: Thank you very much!